# Группировка в LINQ, Подсчет суммы

Tags: c#, linq

Привет коллеги. Есть данные по заказам, кто делает и сколько дней, вытянул основные поля это имя сотрудника и кол-во дней на выполнение заказа:

```
new OrderDetailsMini()
                           {
                               name = detailse.Employee.Name,
                               days = detailse.Price.TimeCraft * detailse.Count
                           });
```

Таких вот строк в коллекции много. Как мне сгруппировать людей по имени и посчитать сумму всех дней, которые им нужны на заказы? Можно это в LINQ сделать или нет? В SQL то легко, а вот что-то с EF я немного застрял.

Comment: Покажите в sql что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: `data.GroupBy(x => x.name, x=>x.days).Select(x => new OrderDetailsMini {name = x.Key, days = x.Sum()})`

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Видно мне LINQ еще учить и учить. :)

Comment: @FoggyFinder Сделал ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для группировки данных используйте `GroupBy`, для суммирования - `Sum`. Пример:

```
data
    .GroupBy(x => x.name, x=>x.days)
    .Select(x => new OrderDetailsMini {name = x.Key, days = x.Sum()})
```

Comment: А зачем в  .GroupBy( x=x.days)? Мы же по нем агрегатную вызываем?

Comment: @RomanIeromenko Присмотритесь, там группировка для имени, для дней просто селектор

Comment: Но ведь нам нужна сумма дней, сгруппированная по имени

Comment: вот этот код `.GroupBy(x => x.name, x=>x.days)` создаст группы, где в каждой группе ключем будет имя, а набором значений - дни для этого имени. Поэтому дальше, в селекторе, я могу трансформировать каждую группу в 1 запись, выписав из ней ключ (который имя) и суммировав дни, что и требовалось

Answer (score 0):

Смею поправить

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<OrderDetailsMini> datal;
        datal = new List<OrderDetailsMini>();
        datal.Add(new OrderDetailsMini("Ваня", 15));
        datal.Add(new OrderDetailsMini("Ваcя", 25));
        datal.Add(new OrderDetailsMini("Егор", 5));
        datal.Add(new OrderDetailsMini("Ваня", 15));
        datal.Add(new OrderDetailsMini("Вера", 8));
        datal.Add(new OrderDetailsMini("Егор", 21));
        var spor = datal.GroupBy(x => x.name, x => x.days).Select(x=> new 
        OrderDetailsMini (x.Key, x.Sum())).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in spor)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name :{0}, days total :{1}",item.name, item.days);
        }
    }


class OrderDetailsMini
{
    public string name;
    public int days;


    public OrderDetailsMini(string name, int days)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.days = days;
    }
}
```

Результат во изображении[image: введите сюда описание изображения]